# Laravel rules * mensaje en campos múltiple con vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validación

```
<tr v-for="(data,index) in ListaAsistencia" v-bind:key='data.id' >
    <td>
        <input style="width: 100%;" v-model="ListaAsistencia[index].cargo" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width: 100%;" v-model="ListaAsistencia[index].cargo" />
        <!-- objetivo es identifica la asignacion del campo y me imprima el mansaje  -->
        <span  v-if="validacion.lista_asistencia+'.'+[index]+'.'+area" >
            Mensaje
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

en la cual me envía la petición

```
ListaAsistencia:[
  {id:1,area:'123'},
  {id:3,area:'345'}
]
```

en el controlador se valida los datos no este vacio

```
 protected $rules = [
    "lista_asistencia.*.area"  => "required|string|min:3",
    "lista_asistencia.*.empresa"  => "required|string|min:3",
   ];
 
 public function store(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    }
}
```

en la cual me retorna el siguiente mensaje, hasta aquí funciona todo bien

```
lista_asistencia.0.empresa: ["El campo lista_asistencia.0.empresa es obligatorio."]
  0: "El campo lista_asistencia.0.empresa es obligatorio."
lista_asistencia.1.area: ["El campo lista_asistencia.1.area es obligatorio."]
  0: "El campo lista_asistencia.1.area es obligatorio."
lista_asistencia.1.empresa: ["El campo lista_asistencia.1.empresa es obligatorio."]
  0: "El campo lista_asistencia.1.empresa es obligatorio."
```

yo como puedo imprimir el siguiente valor ya que se deber imprimir por el orden de la lista, he intentado con todo y nada

```
<tr v-for="data in lista_asistencia" >
   <td>
      <div v-if='validacion.lista_asistencia.1.area'> Mensaje </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

pude obtener la validación de los campo mutiles por el cual los campos se poner en rojo si la validación bota un error

```
<tr v-for="(data,index) in lista_asistencia" >
       <input style="width: 100%;" v-model="data.item.fecha" :class="{'is-invalid-sst': isKeyExists(validacion, 'listaInduccionRelacion.' + [index] + '.fecha')}" />
</tr>
    
        
methods: {
    
  isKeyExists(obj, key) {
      //console.info(key);
      if (obj[key] == undefined) {
           return false;
      } else {
           return true;
      }
  },
    ...
}
```